# Computing Riemann sum for the following function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

Find $\mathcal{L}(f,P)$ and $\mathcal{U}(f,P)$ for an arbitrary partition $P$ of $[0,1]$, e.g. $0=x_0<x_1<\cdots<x_n=1$. ($\mathcal{L}(f,P)$ and $\mathcal{U}(f,P)$ are the lower and upper Riemann sums, respectively.)

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x,  & \text{if }x\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1], \\
1, & \text{if } x\in (\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q})\cap[0,1]
\end{cases}$$

It's formally clear that $\mathcal{U}(f,P)=1$ by the density of the irrationals in $\mathbb{R}$. And intuitively, it's clear that $\mathcal{L}(f,P)=\frac12$, but I'm don't really have an idea on how to justify that formally. Anyone got a trick?

Edit: I've managed to prove that $\mathcal{L}(f,P)\geq \frac12$ using the uniform partition: let $x_k=\frac{k}n$ for $k=0,\cdots,1$. Then $\mathcal{L}(f,P)$ for this partition is

$$\sum_{k=1}^n(x_k-x_{k-1})\inf_{[x_{k-1},x_k]}f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1n\left(\frac{k-1}n\right)=\frac1{n^2}\frac{n^2 - n}{2}\to\frac12$$

when $n\to\infty$. However, how can I prove that $\mathcal{L}(f,P)$ is in fact equal to $\frac12$?

Comment: You can't, because it isn't.  That is its limit as the mesh of your partition gets finer, but it is not the actual value.  The actual value does depend on the particular partition chosen.  In fact, even your carefully chosen partition doesn't equal exactly 1/2!

Answer (score 1):

By definition:
$$L(f,P)=\sum_{i=1}^n\inf_{x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]}\{f(x)\}(x_i-x_{i-1}).$$
Note that, on any sub-interval [a,b] of $[0,1]$, $\inf\limits_{x\in[a,b]}\{f(x)\}=a$, 
since $f(x)\geq x$, thus $a$ is a lower bound of $f$ and there exists a sequence of rationals $(q_n)$, such that $q_n\in[a,b]$ and $q_n\to a$. Thus, 
$$\inf_{x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]}\{f(x)\}=x_{i-1}.$$
Now, substituting, we get:
$$L(f,P)=\sum_{i=1}^nx_{i-1}(x_i-x_{i-1})<\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{x_{i-1}+x_i}{2}(x_i-x_{i-1})=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2-x_{i-1}^2=\frac{1}{2}(1-0)=\frac{1}{2}.$$
So, $L(f,P)$ is **strictly** below $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: But it should be 1/2 in the limit as the mesh gets finer, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yeap, in general. but **only** as a limit, not actually. That is, you can find a sequence of partitions $P_n$ such that $L(f,P_n)\to\frac{1}{2}$, but there is no actual partition that is equal to $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Yes, that's what I implied, only as a limit. Thank you.